# TextView not showing even I can see it on design and other views showing

Tags: android, textview

I have RelativeLayout which contains images and texts. images are showing but text not showing even I can see them on design.
I use bellow XML in include tag inside CoordinatorLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/toptoolbarview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="48dp"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:paddingTop="5dp"
android:paddingBottom="5dp">
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0.5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/black" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/sort"
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/provider_not_found"
    android:src="@drawable/sort" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sortTxt"
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/sort"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    tools:text="@string/sort" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Bellow where the above xml included:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                             android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                             android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                                             tools:context="io.github.luizgrp.sectionedrecyclerviewadapter.demo.HomeActivity">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppBarOverlay">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/PopupOverlay"/>
```

<----- THIS where I include the XML contains the above code --- >

```
    <include
        layout="@layout/toptoolbar"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp" />
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_home"
    />

<include
    android:id="@+id/inc_bot_nav"
    layout="@layout/bottom_nav"
  />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[First Image showing the running application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVUyo.png)
[Second image showing the code in android design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CY0z.png)

As you can see from the images and XML seems every thing should be OK.
What Is wrong with my code?
any help thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `android:text="@string/sort"` instead of `tools:text="@string/sort"` in your TextView

According to [docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes#tools_instead_of_android)

> You can insert sample data in your layout preview by using the tools: prefix instead of android: with any  attribute from the Android framework. This is useful when the attribute's value isn't populated until runtime but you want to see the effect beforehand, in the layout preview.
>
> For example, if the android:text attribute value is set at runtime or you want to see the layout with a value different than the default, you can add tools:text to specify some text for the layout preview only.

Comment: Thanks This is what was missing. did not noticed that.